# Angular 2 Jasmine unit test dynamic id

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I have problems trying to unit test my application.

I have an created an dynamic navbar that generates out of JSON objects. The navbar have an list created out of ngFor and I have problems accessing the id when writing my jasmine driven unit tests.

The generating hmtl:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of this.children" id="child-navbars">
  <div *ngIf="this.showMenu[item.parentIndex]" id="child-navbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a *ngIf="item.link!=missingLinkCode"  routerLink={{item.link}} class="nav-link" id="{{item.name}}">{{item.name}}</a></li>
      <li><a *ngIf="item.link==missingLinkCode" class="nav-link" id="{{item.name}}">{{item.name}}</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

In my chrome browser the ***id is set properly*** and the navbar works as intended. When trying to find the element in my tests however the queryselector can't find the id.

```
c.children = [{"name": "Applications", "parentIndex": 1, "link":"applications"}];
c.init();
fixture.detectChanges();
console.log(fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('#Applications').innerHTML)
```

The code above logs null.

If I however have an static id, resulting several list items with the same id, unit test code above can find it.

How do I unit test dynamic id?

Comment: are you sure the element is already added/rendered?

Comment: May be you forgot to set `c.showMenu[1] = true;`? Try to log all template by `console.log(fixture.nativeElement.innerHTML);`

Comment: Haha, wow, that seems to have been the problem! I didn't manage to get the parents to show either but I guess an mix of earlier efforts now makes everything work. Thanks for finding that simple fix :)
Post an answer and I will accept it!